# rectangular matrix munkres pattern based columns mutually exclusive allocation

Tags: python-2.7, hungarian-algorithm

Here I am providing Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of my problem:

Rectangular matrix of size 3 X 17 is considered:
rows = [10,6,9] considered.
where the columns are patterns each associated with a value

```
example file: "patterns_list"  <pattern <space> associated value>
['2','3'] 12  
['2','1'] 11  
['2','5'] 11  
['3','4'] 10  
['3','5'] 9  
['4','1'] 9  
['4','5'] 9  
['3','6'] 8  
['4','6'] 8  
['1','5'] 8  
['2'] 7  
['1','6'] 7  
['3'] 5  
['4'] 5  
['1'] 4  
['5'] 4  
['6'] 3
```

Now, the difference between the column value and row value is considered as cost in the matrix 3 X 17 and if the cost turned out to be negative it is replaced with summation of all column values (nothing specific but to ensure some huge value). Now minimum cost allocation need to be done. I installed the library *munkres* using *sudo apt-get install python-munkres*
and ran the following code:

```
from munkres import Munkres, print_matrix
import linecache

rows=[10,6,9]
v=[]
diff=[]
value=[]
f = open("patterns_list","r")
for line in f:
        line=line.strip()
        line=line.split(' ')
        v.append(int(line[1]))
total=sum(v)
for i in range(0,len(rows)):
        for j in range(0,len(v)):
                x=v[j]-rows[i]
                if x<0:
                        value.append(total)
                else:
                        value.append(v[j]-rows[i])
        diff.append(value)
        value=[]

matrix=diff

m = Munkres()
indexes = m.compute(matrix)
print_matrix(matrix, msg='Lowest cost through this matrix:\n')
total = 0
patterns=[]
print "Allocation indices:"
for row, column in indexes:
    value = matrix[row][column]
    total += value
    print '(%d, %d) -> %d' % (row, column, value)
    patterns.append(int(column))

print 'total cost: %d' % total
print "Corresponding allocated patterns:\n"
for i in range(0,len(patterns)):
    line = linecache.getline("patterns_list",patterns[i])
    print line
```

The following output is generated:

```
Lowest cost through this matrix:

[  2,   1,   1,   0, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130]
[  6,   5,   5,   4,   3,   3,   3,   2,   2,   2,   1,   1, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130]
[  3,   2,   2,   1,   0,   0,   0, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130]
Allocation indices:
(0, 3) -> 0
(1, 10) -> 1
(2, 4) -> 0
total cost: 1
Corresponding allocated patterns:

['2','5'] 11

['1','5'] 8

['3','4'] 10
```

The issue is [2,5],[1,5],[3,4] are the finally allocated patterns which corresponds to minimum cost. Here the patterns [2,5],[1,5] are not mutually exclusive. '5' is there in common. Once r1 got [2,5] allocated, then rest of the patterns containing any of the element of allocated i.e.,2,5 here should not be available for allocation or corresponding pattern associated costs in the matrix should be updated to too high value, so that those no more considered to next row and should proceed like this.

Means ultimately if allocation is possible, the corresponding patterns should be mutually exclusive in nature.

Can anyone please suggest how to tackle this?

Comment: The indices in the matrix corresponding to minimum cost are (0,3), (1,10), and (2,4). None of those conflict. ps: This is not Python 3.x (the print statements are wrong). pps: `column` looks to already be an int. You shouldn't have to specify that.

Comment: Thanks for the tag clearance. The column value is taken from a file, so it is of type string. To perform arithmetic on those values , I need to convert to int.

Comment: (0,3) corresponds to [2,5] and 91,10) corresponds to [1,5] in the column. [2,5] and [1,5] have 5 in common so that is the conflict. Once [2,5] is allocated to r1, for r2 any column having either '2' or 5' should not be considered.'

Answer (score 1):

**The Good News:** There is a way to solve this problem.
**The Bad News:** There is no *easy* way to solve this problem.

**What is the problem?**
After doing some preliminary calculations, you have a 2D cost matrix and a list of sets - one for each column in the cost matrix. The objective is to select as many indices in the cost matrix as possible, given that

- no two selected indices (assignments) lie within the same row or column,
- the sets associated with the columns of the assignments are disjoint, and
- the sum of the assignments is minimized.

**What is the solution?**
This problem can be viewed as an instance of a N-dimensional assignment problem. The first two dimensions of the problem (the two dimensions of the cost matrix) are fairly apparent. The rest of the dimensions may not be so apparent.

First, we will want to create a superset containing all of the values from the other sets. The size of this superset - plus the two dimensions of the cost matrix - is the value of N in this N-dimensional assignment problem. In your example our superset is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, and our N is thus 8.

In our 2-dimensional cost matrix, each cost in the matrix can be located by its row and column numbers. For example, the cost at (1, 3) is 4. For a 8-dimensional cost matrix, each cost will be located using 8 position numbers. Fortunately, we can calculate these position numbers iteratively.

```
rows = [10,6,9]

import ast
from munkres import print_matrix

listOfSets = []
v = []
with open("patterns_list","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        listOfSets.append(ast.literal_eval(line.strip().replace("'","").split(" ")[0]))
        v.append(int(line.strip().split(" ")[1]))

total = sum(v)
matrix = []
for row in rows:
    values = []
    for num in v:
        x = num-row
        values.append(total if x<0 else x)
    matrix.append(values)

superset = list(set().union(*listOfSets))
counter = [1] * len(superset)
newMatrix = []
for row in range(0, len(rows)):
    for column in range(0, len(v)):
        if matrix[row][column] == total:
            break
        temp = [matrix[row][column], row, column]
        for n in range(0, len(superset)):
            if superset[n] in listOfSets[column]:
                temp.append(0)
            else:
                temp.append(counter[n])
                counter[n] += 1
        newMatrix.append(temp)

print_matrix(newMatrix, msg="New Matrix = [ value, row, column, dimension1position, dimension2position...]")
```

Now we have a list containing every value from the 2D cost matrix (that wasn't the dummy value) and its associated position within our new N-dimensional matrix. I chose to do it this way instead of actually making the full N-dimensional matrix as the full N-dimensional matrix would be very large and mostly filled with dummy values. However, the full N-dimensional matrix could very easily be created from this list if necessary. Running a multidimensional assignment problem solver on this N-dimensional array will give you the answer you want. However, as far as I know, code for a multidimensional assignment problem solver does not exist. You will have to code that yourself.

ps: I cleaned up your original code a bit.

```
rows=[10,6,9]

from munkres import Munkres, print_matrix
import linecache

v=[]
with open("patterns_list","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        v.append(int(line.strip().split(" ")[1]))

total=sum(v)
matrix=[]
for row in rows:
    values=[]
    for num in v:
        x=num-row
        values.append(total if x<0 else x)
    matrix.append(values)

print_matrix(matrix, msg="Cost Matrix:")

indices = Munkres().compute(matrix)
total = 0
patterns=[]
print "\nAllocated Indices:"
for row, column in indices:
    value = matrix[row][column]
    total += value
    print "(%d, %d) -> %d" % (row, column, value)
    patterns.append(column)

print "Total Cost: %d" % total

print "\nCorresponding Allocated Patterns:"
for pattern in patterns:
    print linecache.getline("patterns_list",pattern),
```

Comment: I could not understand the N dimension concept. And here superset=[1,2,3,4,5,6], 7 is not there. Could you please elaborate your approach. Could you provide MCVE on the n-dimensional matrix generation part you coded.

Comment: Yes. It has a bug right now though. I'll get that fixed and put it up.

Comment: The bug has been fixed. I also expanded to code to be runnable. It will print the new matrix. It's late. I'm going to sleep. I'll see about explaining it more when I wake up.